# Extra Backslash in Json String when exposing webservice

Tags: json, rest-service, apex-webservice

I am creating a middle ware in Salesforce. The external System1 calls my SFDC org and I call external system2 from SFDC in turn. The external system2 gives me Json string like {"Car":"Fiat","Model":"2009"}. 
I use the following code to return back the json to the calling external system1

```
//Call external system2 and get response. No DML in between Only Callouts
RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return '{"Car":"Fiat","Model":"2009"}';
```

But i get extra backslash like this in response from SFDC org

"{\"Car\":\"Fiat\",\"Model\":\"2009\"}"

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are returning a String from your REST endpoint which is then being sanitised by Salesforce JSON serializer.

Any object returned from a method in an `@RestResource` annotated class is automatically serialized into JSON/XML for you, you don't need to do it yourself.

If you want to return a JSON object from an `@RestResource` class you have two choices.

### Create the object as a class and return an instance of it

```
global class MyRestObject {
    global String Car;
    global String Model;
}

// Then in your RestResource method
RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
MyRestObject obj = new MyRestObject();
obj.Car = 'Fiat';
obj.Model = '2009';
return obj;
```

You will also have the change the return type of you method from `String` to `MyRestObject` for this to work. The Salesforce JSON serializer will turn it into JSON for you before it returns it to callers of your REST endpoint.

### Set the body directly

```
RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"Car":"Fiat","Model":"2009"}');
```

In this case you do have to do the conversion to JSON yourself (or you could use the object from the first example above with `JSON.serialize()`).

You will also have the change the return type of your method from `String` to `void` for this to work. Only return values are run through the Salesforce serializer, so by returning nothing you are telling Salesforce to leave the body of your response alone.

Comment: Thanks it Worked . Used the second approach of setting the body directly. Thanks once again.